# how to display foreign key value to template django

Tags: python, django

hello guys so i have a bit of problem here, i want to display my foreign key value to my form but it seems its not doing showing anything at all so i tried to print it from the backend like this:

```
     task = task_admin_form.objects.all()
     for tasks in task.values():
          print(tasks.username.username)
```

but its not working can anyone help me with this? thanks

my model

```
    class task_admin_form(models.Model):
        username = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        task_tenggat = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
        task = models.TextField(max_length=200)
        
        def __str__(self):
            return self.username
```

Account model

```
    class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
        email                   = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
        username                = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
        gambar                  = models.ImageField(blank=False, null=False, upload_to='pics')
        date_joined             = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
        last_login              = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
        is_admin                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_active               = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        is_staff                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_superuser            = models.BooleanField(default=False)

        USERNAME_FIELD = "username"
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["email"]

        objects = MyAccountManager()

        def __str__(self):
            return self.username
        
        def has_perm(self,perm,obj=None):
            return self.is_admin
        
        def has_module_perms(self,app_label):
            return True
```

views.py

```
task = task_admin_form.objects.all()
return render(request,"form.html",{"task":task})
```

form.html(the username is a field in my other model)

```
                    <div class="block">
                    <label>TO: </label>
                    <select name="username">
                        {% for form in task %}
                        <option value={{form.username.username}} >{{form.username.username}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                </div>
```

Comment: replace form_task with task

Comment: your context is {"task":task} and you are trying to access a name that doesn't exist "form_task"

Comment: sorry for that, ill update my question

Comment: sorry that supposed to be task so it will be {% for form in task %}

Comment: def __str__(self):
            return self.username   in task_admin_form is referring to a foreign key

Comment: replace it to self.username.username

Comment: i tried it but it still not working

Comment: Mohit Harsan: do i need to add the data first to the task_admin_form to get the foreign key value? because the task_admin_form as now don't have any data inside it but the  foreign key that is account have data of username,image,etc ( but what i need is that i can choose freely what admin that in account to give task to in my template)

Comment: you are trying to access a value inside task_admin_form , so ofcourse you need to add data to it first.. Your use case is diffferent . i will  post answer here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Account is a Foreign key to task_user_form named username. To allow user to select an Account you have to assign the ForeignKey field.

In your views:

```
accounts = Account.objects.all()
return render(request,"form.html",{"accounts": accounts})
```

Then , in your template:

```
{% for account in accounts %}
     <option value={{account.id}}>{{acount.username}}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Here you are selecting an option which has vaue which points to Account Object (id). You have to assign this to the task_user_form object.

Comment: ohh that's how it work i am a bit confused how Django orm work, thanks dude its working now i add this in my view so accounting = Account.objects.get(id=admin_name)         data = task_admin_form(username=accounting,subject=subject,task_tenggat=tanggal_tenggat,task=task)
        data.save()

Comment: that is correct .can you upvote the answer please @adhi_wika